# How to make only the call-to-action button clickable in a SwiftUI implementation with Google Mobile Ads SDK, flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, swiftui, google-mobile-ads

I'm working on a flutter project where I'm trying to implement a native video ad using SwiftUI with the Google Mobile Ads SDK for iOS. The official documentation primarily focuses on creating native ad layouts using XIB, but I want to create a custom native ad layout using SwiftUI.

I have successfully displayed the native ad's components (icon, headline, body text, call-to-action button, etc.) using SwiftUI, but I'm struggling to make only the call-to-action button clickable. I don't want the whole ad to be clickable, just the call-to-action button.

Here's my current implementation:

NativeVideoAdFactory class

```html
import google_mobile_ads
import SwiftUI

class NativeVideoAdFactory: FLTNativeAdFactory {
    
    
    
    func createNativeAd(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd, customOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil) -> GADNativeAdView {

        let nativeAdView = GADNativeAdView()

        let contentView = NativeVideoAdView(nativeAd: nativeAd)

        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nativeAdView.addSubview(controller.view)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nativeAdView.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nativeAdView.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nativeAdView.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nativeAdView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        
        nativeAdView.callToActionView = controller.view
        nativeAdView.nativeAd = nativeAd
        
        nativeAdView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return nativeAdView
        
    }
}
```

NativeVideoAdView

```html
import SwiftUI
import google_mobile_ads

struct NativeVideoAdView: View {
    let nativeAd: GADNativeAd

    var body: some View {
        
// some codes
                
       HStack {
                //ad call to action
                
                if let callToAction = nativeAd.callToAction {
                
                    
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Text(callToAction)
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .background(Color(hex: "#FFBF00")) // Amber color
                    .cornerRadius(10)
     
                }
            }
             
// the rest of the code
    }
}
```

VideoMediaViewRepresentable

```html
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds

struct VideoMediaViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let nativeAd: GADNativeAd

    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GADMediaView {
        let mediaView = GADMediaView()
        mediaView.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent
        return mediaView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GADMediaView, context: Context) {
       
   
        uiView.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent
        
    }
}
```

*Take note that in this implementation, the whole ad is clickable but that is not what i want, i want only the callToAction button to be clickable.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to make only the call-to-action button clickable in a SwiftUI implementation with Google Mobile Ads SDK? Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: So in essence you are trying to display a view from the native (ios) side to the flutter side . You also want to be able to send a click action from the flutter side and perform some logic. You'll need to use platform channels for communicating between flutter and ios and also use platform views to display the native ad you're written in swiftUI as a flutter view

Comment: no i didnt say i have to perform additional logic. The logics are being handled by the google_mobile_ads plugin. I just wanted to find a way to only make the callToAction button clickable and not the whole ad.